# How to use Powershell Invoke-RestMethod to POST a file

Tags: php, rest, powershell

I want to use PowerShell to upload a file to my website using POST method. However, I received the error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : 
>       401 Unauthorized
>       Unauthorized
>       This server could not verify that you
>       are authorized to access the document
>       requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
>       credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
>       browser doesn't understand how to supply
>       the credentials required.

This is the client side code:

```
$uri = "https://mywebpage.domain.net/restapi/put/"
$username = "someuser"
$password = "somepasswd"
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username+":"+$password))}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -contentType "multipart/form-data" -Method Post -Headers $headers -InFile "stats2.json"
```

And this is the server side code (in PHP) (and I know, I'm still not checking if the user is authorized to upload a file):

```
public function put() {

    $username = null;
    $password = null;

    // mod_php
    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
        $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    // most other servers
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {

            if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']),'basic')===0)
              list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));

    }

    if (is_null($username)) {

        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';

        die();

    }

    // En versiones de PHP anteriores a la 4.1.0, debería utilizarse $HTTP_POST_FILES en lugar
    // de $_FILES.

    $dir_subida = 'data/';
    $fichero_subido = $dir_subida . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
        //echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The file cannot be uploaded. The incident has been reported.\n";
        error_log("The file " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . " cannot be uploaded from " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }

    //echo 'Más información de depuración:';
    //print_r($_FILES);

    echo '</pre>';

    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../data/stats2.json", $json);   



}
```

The put() function is a member of a class that is used to handle the request.

Comment: _or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required._ It's not necessarily your _browser_. Try ome debugging. E.g. instead of sending 401 Header, echo out the provided credentials.

Comment: Thanks!, but how can I see the echoed output from PowerShell?

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` (Or `iwr`) instead of `Invoke-RestMethod` and its Content Property

Comment: Can you show some example? I don't see any Content property for the Invoke-WebRequest object.

Comment: `iwr "https://google.de" | Get-Member` lists Content, doesn't it?